# ASP.NET 5 EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final issue - Compiler wants 7.0.0.0 to be referenced which is not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dnu

I am having the same issue. I have added the following dependencies in my `project.json` file:

```html
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
...
```

I used `dnu install EntityFramework` and `dnu install EntityFramework.SqlServer` to install the packages. `"EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4",` was written under `dependencies` node automatically by the installer itself.

Issue / Question 1: To my surprise when I was pulling in the intellisence for `EntityFramework` the available version I am presenting with is only `6.1.3`!

Issue 2: When I am compiling my application using `dnu build` (I ran `dnu restore` command after adding `EntityFramework` assemblies (`.Core` and `.Commands`) manually under `dependencies` node I am getting a bunch of compilation errors:

```html
The type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework.Core, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(12,41): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0308: The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(13,32): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0308: The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(14,29): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Books' and no extension method 'Books' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(15,42): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Authors' and no extension method 'Authors' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(17,43): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Authors' and no extension method 'Authors' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(19,45): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Authors' and no extension method 'Authors' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(22,29): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Books' and no extension method 'Books' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\Models\SampleData.cs(61,29): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' and no extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I remove `.Core` and `.Commands` assembly references the project build fine.

Then I changed the version for `EntityFramework.Core` to `7.0.0.0` as mentioned in the error:

```html
The type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework.Core, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

But `dnu restore` now gave me the following:

```html
Unable to locate Dependency EntityFramework.Core >= 7.0.0
Writing lock file D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 6675ms elapsed

Errors in D:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\project.json
    Unable to locate Dependency EntityFramework.Core >= 7.0.0
```

I am a newbie in `asp.net 5` `Visual Studio code` platform. And I cannot use `Visual Studio 2015` as other members of the dev team are using OSX.

This is a learning project for me. Requirement is pretty straight forward. Connect a SQL Server database, pull `master-child` relational data using Entity Framework.

Screwed up! Help!!

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

1. I can see the major changes in `project.json` for all packages with version `7.0.0-rc1-final`. I used Yeoman generator tool to create the project but looks like you corrected the package through `Visual Studio`. So, do I have to update the package version manually and `restore` them?
2. When the project was created/generated by Yeoman, there was no `global.json` file added by default. Can I add this manually and put the code inside by hand? Will this work?
3. I can also see some additional package references are added to `project.json` file which were not added by default by Yeoman generator - like `Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` etc. Are they all being used effectively in the project? Because the generator did not add them automatically, again, can I add them manually and restore using `dnu restore`? Will this have any impact on the project if I add them manually?

Comment: Please don't use code snippets when they're not functional.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should **remove** `"EntityFramework"` from dependencies (remove the line `"EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4"`) and use

```
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

only. You don't need to add `"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` explicitly if you added `"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` because of the following dependencies:

```
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final":
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-rc1-final":
        "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

I mean that `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` requires `EntityFramework.Relational`, which requires `EntityFramework.Core`.

You should verify additionally that `global.json` contains `"sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1" }`.

**UPDATED**: I examined the test project which you uploaded. It had many small problems. I modified it. You can download the modified project [**here**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/Test_Project.zip). **Don't forget to fix the `ConnectionString` used in `appsettings.json`, it contains the `Server` which I used at me.**

The most important changes are the usage of more simple `BookContext.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace apiservice.Models {
    public class BookContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the usage of the following `SampleData.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace apiservice.Models
{
    public static class SampleData
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
            var context=serviceProvider.GetService<BookContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
            if (!context.Books.Any()) {
                var austen = context.Authors.Add(
                    new Author { LastName = "Austen", FirstName = "Jane" }).Entity;
                var dickens = context.Authors.Add(
                    new Author { LastName = "Dickens", FirstName = "Charles" }).Entity;
                var cervantes = context.Authors.Add(
                    new Author { LastName = "Cervantes", FirstName = "Miguel" }).Entity;

                context.Books.AddRange(
                    new Book {
                        Title = "Pride and Prejudice",
                        Year = 1813,
                        Author = austen,
                        Price = 9.99M,
                        Genre = "Comedy of manners"
                    },
                    new Book {
                        Title = "Northanger Abbey",
                        Year = 1817,
                        Author = austen,
                        Price = 12.95M,
                        Genre = "Gothic parody"
                    },
                    new Book {
                        Title = "David Copperfield",
                        Year = 1850,
                        Author = dickens,
                        Price = 15,
                        Genre = "Bildungsroman"
                    },
                    new Book {
                        Title = "Don Quixote",
                        Year = 1617,
                        Author = cervantes,
                        Price = 8.95M,
                        Genre = "Picaresque"
                    }
                );

                context.SaveChanges(); 
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

the usage of `project.json` with the following `dependencies` part:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.1"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

fixing of `appsettings.json` from

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection":{
            "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=BookStore;User Id=sa; Password=******;Trusted_Connection=true;"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=BookStore;User Id=sa; Password=******;Trusted_Connection=true;"
    }
  }
}
```

(`Data` should **not be under `Logging`**)

and the usage of the following `Startup.cs`

```cs
using apiservice.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;


namespace apiservice
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration {get; set;}

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<BookContext>(options => 
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])
                );

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // we need to execute the following two commands before

            //    dnu restore
            //    dnx ef migrations add Initial
            //    dnx ef database update   

            // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<BookContext>()
                         .Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch { }

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            SampleData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

I wrote in the comment inside of `Configure` method that one should execute the commands

```
dnx ef migrations add Initial
dnx ef database update
```

after all packages are restored. `dnx ef migrations add Initial` will create additional `Migrations` folder in the project with the files like `20160101205609_Initial.cs` and `BookContextModelSnapshot.cs`. The database defined in `appsettings.json` will be created by `dnx ef database update` and it will be filled with test data from `SampleData.cs` during forking with the program.

By the way I moved `package.json` inside of the package folder (on the same level as `project.json`). You use the packages not, but the movement makes the npm packages visible and management in Visual Studio.

Comment: If I have understood correctly I now have this:
`"EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"`

Compilation errors coming up are:

`...The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments...The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments`

Comment: I forgot to ask, I cannot find a global.json in my project tree. It's a Web API I am developing with VS Code and the project generated using Yeoman generator.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: Could you include **full `project.json`** which you use currently. It would be mostly simple if you upload somewhere your test project and I could compile it on my computer. What I mean in my answer, that you **don't need** to include `EntityFramework.Core` and `EntityFramework.Relational` if you included `"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` - the dependencies of `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` will be loaded automatically.

Comment: May I send the project to you through email or something? I don't have a server yet where I can upload! Meanwhile I removed .Core and .Relational references. However, still getting `'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments` error when compiling.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: You can send me to oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com. I use Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, but in general command line tool should work too. The typical structure of the project should be: the main folder of the solution with `global.json` and optional `NuGet.Config` file (see [here](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file)). Then you have `src` subfolder which contains the folder for every project in your solution. Every project contains `project.json`.

Comment: Thank you! I am preparing the project.

Comment: Hi, I sent you a zip via wetransfer.com. Please download from http://we.tl/ibgivBpskU. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: I wrote **UPDATED** part to my answer. You can download modified project from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/Test_Project.zip)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Everything works now. However, I put some questions under UPDATE section of my original question. If you please enlighten me on those that would be extremely helpful for me :)

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: You are welcome! I added some dependencies manually. Some from there like `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` are really very important for the code `Startup.cs`, which I use. Sorry, but I don't use `Yeoman` myself, but even the generators used by Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 works not correctly. For example I found that your demo looks very close to [the tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html), but the text on docs.asp.net miss many things and the current template of "Web Application" don't add all dependencies.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: [The tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html) don't contains important steps with creating of `BookContext.cs` (`ApplicationDbContext.cs`), the step [Add scaffolding](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html#add-scaffolding) don't work at all because one didn't had any "Add scaffolding" and "MVC 6 Controller with views, using Entity Framework". After reading [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/290#issuecomment-158465907) I added `Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc` and other.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar: In other words, one can say: ASP.NET 5 is still not final and one have many small problems. One can of cause create `global.json` and optionally `NuGet.config` in the parent directory of the project directory (not only `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.config`). I would recommend you to look [the video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DevRadio/DR1619) which could be helpful for you. In general it's really not simple to support `project.json` now. We can hope that it will be more simple in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the gentle push I needed on a "similar" project (don't think it's the same, but it's damn close)

Comment: @Oleg, Tnx 4 your example code, I downloaded it.
The only thing maybe people here will have to know is to run first: "dnvm upgrade" from the cmd in order to be able to use dnx.