# Generate DBContext from models [Code First]

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I do not have a database "Yet", and I've created my models which are annotated in a folder but when trying to create the initial migration using the command `dnx ef migrations add Initial` I gives me the `error No DbContext was found`.

I thought it would generate the DBContext from the annotations I added to my Models, **My question is** - Is there a command to generate the DBContext from my annotated models or do I have to write the DBContext manually when there is no database?

Comment: You should add one file with definition of DBContext like `public class MyDBContext : DbContext { DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; } ... }`. You can define multiple context for different databases in one program. You should use additional parameter to specify which dbcontext needed be created. You can download demo project from [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34556712/315935).

Comment: @Oleg Thanks a lot that was helpful

Comment: I'm glad if I could help you. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always when I'm using Code First I have to manually create DBContext (and I think that it wouldn't create automatically any DbContext anyway). So you created your model ye? After that I create `DbContext` class (I'm always creating for this `DAL` folder) and in this class:

```
public class YourDBContextClassName : DbContext
    {
        public YourDBContextClassName () : base("YourDBContextClassName ") 
        {

        }

        public DbSet<YourModelName> YourName { get; set; }
        //other models
        //with YourName if you have for example Book Model then it could be something like this:
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

This `base` is from `Web.config` file and the name must match with name in `connectionStrings`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourDBContextClassName " connectionString="Data Source=(localdb);Initial Catalog=YourCatalogDB;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Of course connectionString can be diffrent in your case.